# How to make a query when have array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables: client, project and client_project.

I want to show in a view all the projects of one client.

Here is the explained code:

```
<?php

public function editClient($id)
{
    $client = Client::find($id);

    // I get an array with client_id and project_id of the clients 
    // which is the same I pass in the URL.
    $client_project = DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id',$id)->get();

    // return view('cms.public.views.clients.editclient')->withClient($client);
}
```

Now I want to show the name of projects when the field id of table projects have the same value of project_id in $client_project array.

Here is the example of how to do it if it's only one value, maybe can help.

```
public function editClient($id) 
{
    $client = Client::find($id);
    $client_project = DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id',$id)->first()->project_id;
    $project = DB::table('projects')->where('id',$client_project)->first();

    return $project;
}
```

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to make the query @Jackowski

Comment: Hi do you have many to many relationship in the models ?

Comment: Use One to Many relationship.

Comment: In client_project model I have hasmany @Maraboc

Comment: you can take a look at [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) if a prject can have many client then it's a many to many else it's just one to many ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use One to Many relationship.

In Client.php Model

```
public function projects()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'client_id');
}
```

And in your Project.php Model

```
public function client()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Client', 'client_id');
}
```

Now call

```
$client_project = Client::find($id)->projects;
```

You will get details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Since he has a `client_project` table, i think it's safe to say that's a `Many to Many` relationship between `Client` and `Project` models.

Comment: And what I have to do to show the field called slug (name of project) in the blade? If I put {{$client_project}} now I see all the array, and if I make a foreach and put {{$client_project}} it takes me the error `Property [slug] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Can you explain how works the call `$client_project = Client::find($id)->projects;` to show all the data with the same ID? Step by step, please.

Comment: You will get the details information here:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many  .We use Eloquent relationship here. Eloquent provides many query builders. You also can use raw query. But eloquent makes it easy. Here first we find the client. Then we find the client project via eloquent.

Comment: You can also read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent .here you will get more information about the model.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking the `first()` client project, take them all and use the `whereIn()` method in project selection.

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')->whereIn('id', function ($query) {
        $query->select('project_id')->from('client_project')->where('client_id', $id);
})->get();
```

Here's the laravel documentation link: [Laravel 5.5 Documentation - Queries#where-clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses)

I'm answering on what I've understood about your request which is not very clear.

Comment: Can you put the code with the whereIn? to have clear in which function you say.

Comment: Added a small code snippet. Didn't test it but it should work.